# Match all nodes and return nodes + relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the latest version of Cypher, I can use this query to get all nodes with relationships:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) RETURN n,r,m
```

However, I'm missing nodes without any relationships.

In trying to query the missing nodes, this attempt gives me the error: `Variable 'r' not defined`

```
MATCH (n) WHERE NOT (n)-[r]->() RETURN n
```

And, this attempt shows zero results:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->() WHERE r is null RETURN n
```

I can see the stragglers with:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

But, then I'm missing the relationships.

How do I phrase my query to find all nodes and all relationships without duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [`OPTIONAL MATCH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/clauses/optional-match/):

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
RETURN n, r, m
```